# Compare two Cells and Return Highest Value from third cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, maxifs

Need help please. I am working on report which shows different names in coloumn A. I want to compare the two cells within the same coloumn and then display the highest value from COL B  into COL C:

```
          COL A     COL B          COL C (OUTPUT RESULT REQUIRED) 
Row 1     USA        $3             $7    
Row 2     USA        $7             - 
Row 3     Italy      $1             $1
Row 4     France     $9             $9
Row 5     France     $2             -
Row 6     France     $4             -
```

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1978-excel-find-max-value-in-a-group.html

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that you have a header row.  Use this formula:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$7/($A$2:$A$7=A2),1),"-")
```

[image]

If you do not have a header row we need to do the IF a little different:

```
=IF(OR(ROW()=1,A1<>INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1)),AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$1:$B$6/($A$1:$A$6=A1),1),"-")
```

---

Edit:

Also if you have Office 365 Excel then you can use MAXIFS() in place of the AGGREGATE:

```
=IF(OR(ROW()=1,A1<>INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1)),MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A1),"-")
```

---

Edit #2

If you are using an older version of Excel(2007 or later) then you will need to use the following array formula:

```
=IF(OR(ROW()=1,A1<>INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1)),MAX(IF($A$1:$A$6=A1,$B$1:$B$6)),"-")
```

Being an array formula one must confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For certain 'flavors' of Excel 2016 (e.g. *Excel for Android phones, Excel Mobile, Excel 2016 w/ Office 365, Excel 2016 for Mac, Excel Online, Excel for iPad, Excel for iPhone, Excel for Android tablet*), pair up the newer MAXIFS with a COUNTIF.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A2)=1, MAXIFS(B:B, A:A, A2), " - ")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it doesn't seem to work. I get a #Name? error every time

Comment: Please read the narrative and use it to confirm your version.

Comment: I do have excel 2016

Comment: I have tried the EDIT # 2; and the result I am getting is "-" for all the countries. No $ is being displayed. yes I did use the SHIFT CTRL ENTER

Comment: You are writing your comments into the wrong response.

Comment: `NOTE: This feature is only available if you have an Office 365 subscription. If you are an Office 365 subscriber, make sure you have the latest version of Office. ` from: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MAXIFS-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883